# Why does my parallel performance top out?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've been playing around with Python a lot lately, and in comparing numerous parallelization packages, I noticed that the performance increase from serial to parallel seems to top out at 6 processes instead of 8--the number of cores my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.8.2) has.

The attached plot compares the timing of different tasks as a function of number of processes (parallel or sequential).  This example is using the python built-int '[multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)' package  'Memory' vs. 'Processor' refers to memory-intensive (just allocating large arrays) vs. computationally intensive (many operations) functions.

What is the cause of the top-out below 8-processes?

[image]

(The 'Time's are averaged over 100 function calls for each number of processes)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

iters       = 100
mem_num     = 1000
pro_num     = 20000
max_procs   = 10

line_width  = 2.0
legend_size = 10
fig_name    = 'timing.pdf'

def UseMemory(num):
    test1 = np.zeros([num,num])
    test2 = np.arange(num*num)
    test3 = np.array(test2).reshape([num, num])
    test4 = np.empty(num, dtype=object)
    return 

def UseProcessor(num):
    test1 = np.arange(num)
    test1 = np.cos(test1)
    test1 = np.sqrt(np.fabs(test1))
    test2 = np.zeros(num)
    for i in range(num): test2[i] = test1[i]
    return np.std(test2)

def MemJob(its): 
    for ii in range(its): UseMemory(mem_num)

def ProJob(its): 
    for ii in range(iters): UseProcessor(pro_num)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print '\nParTest\n'    

    proc_range = np.arange(1,max_procs+1,step=1)

    test_times = np.zeros([len(proc_range),2,2])                 # test_times[num_procs][0-ser,1-par][0-mem,1-pro]
    tot_times  = np.zeros([len(proc_range),2  ])                 #  tot_times[num_procs][0-ser,1-par]

    print ' Testing %2d numbers of processors between [%d,%d]' % (len(proc_range), 1, max_procs)
    print ' Iterations %d, Memory Length %d, Processor Length %d' % (iters, mem_num, pro_num)

    for it in range(len(proc_range)):
        procs = proc_range[it]
        job_arg = procs*[iters]
        print '\n - %2d, Processes = %3d' % (it, procs)

        # --- Test Serial ---
        print ' - - Serial'
        # Test Memory
        all_start = time.time()
        start = time.time()
        map(MemJob, [procs*iters])
        ser_mem_time = time.time() - start

        # Test Processor
        start = time.time()
        map(ProJob, job_arg)
        ser_pro_time = time.time() - start

        ser_time = time.time() - all_start

        # --- Test Parallel : multiprocessing ---
        print ' - - Parallel: multiprocessing'
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=procs)
        # Test Memory
        all_start = time.time()
        start = time.time()
        pool.map(MemJob, job_arg)
        par_mem_time = time.time() - start

        # Test Processor
        start = time.time()
        pool.map(ProJob, job_arg)
        par_pro_time = time.time() - start

        par_time = time.time() - all_start

        print ' - - Collecting'
        ser_mem_time /= procs
        ser_pro_time /= procs
        par_mem_time /= procs
        par_pro_time /= procs
        ser_time     /= procs
        par_time     /= procs

        test_times[it][0] = [ ser_mem_time, ser_pro_time ]
        test_times[it][1] = [ par_mem_time, par_pro_time ]
        tot_times[it]     = [ ser_time    , par_time     ]



    fig = plt.figure()
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of Processes')
    ax.set_ylabel('Time [s]')
    ax.xaxis.grid(True)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
    lines = []
    names = []

    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, test_times[:,0,0], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Serial Memory')
    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, test_times[:,0,1], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Serial Processor')
    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, tot_times[:,0], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Serial')

    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, test_times[:,1,0], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Parallel Memory')
    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, test_times[:,1,1], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Parallel Processor')
    l1, = ax.plot(proc_range, tot_times[:,1], linewidth=line_width)
    lines.append(l1)
    names.append('Parallel')

    plt.legend(lines, names, ncol=2, prop={'size':legend_size}, fancybox=True, shadow=True, bbox_to_anchor=(1.10, 1.10))
    fig.savefig(fig_name,dpi=fig.get_dpi())
    print ' - Saved to ', fig_name
    plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: You forgot to show the code :)

Comment: @LevLevitsky But showing code is like lifting up your dress!  ... Added.

Comment: Your notebook doesn't have 8 cores, it has 4 cores + 4 SMT threads, the speedup probably somehow adds up/tops out to/at ~6. See here for a good link related to that http://superuser.com/questions/279629/how-much-speedup-does-a-hyper-thread-give-in-theory/279803#279803

Comment: @bamboon `sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'` yields 8... that actually means 4+4?

Comment: @bamboon it looks like you were right, I have a 'quad core' with '8 vitual cores'.  Is that the same as 8 hardware 'hyperthreads'?

Comment: @zhermes well yeah, I would say you have 4 CPU cores of which each can execute two "hyperthreads" which adds up 8 in sum.

Comment: @bamboon thanks, if you want to compile your comments into an 'answer' I'll select it

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion above I think you have the information you need, but I'm adding an answer to collect facts in case it benefits others (plus I wanted to work it through myself). (Due credit to @bamboon who mentioned some of this first.)

First, your MacBook has a CPU with four physical cores, but the design of the chip is such that each core's hardware has the ability to run two threads. This is called "simultaneous multithreading" (SMT) and in this case is embodied by Intel's [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) feature. So taken all together you have 8 "virtual cores" (4 + 4 = 8).

Note that the OS treats all the virtual cores the same, i.e. it does not distinguish between the two SMT threads offered by a physical core, and that's why `sysctl` returns 8 when you query it.  Python will do the same thing:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
8
```

Second, the speedup limit you're encountering is a well-known phenomenon in which parallel performance saturates and does not improve with the addition of more processors working on the problem. This effect is described by [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), a quantitative statement about how much speedup to expect from multiple processors depending on how much code can be parallelized and how much runs serially.

Typically a number of factors limit relative speedup, including details of the OS and even the computer's architecture (e.g. how SMT works in a hardware core), so that even if you parallelize as much of your code as you can, your performance will not scale indefinitely. Understanding where the serial bottleneck is can require very detailed analysis of your program and its running environment.

You can find a good example with discussion in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/279629/how-much-speedup-does-a-hyper-thread-give-in-theory/).

I hope this helps.